# calculate epoch time in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, datetime, epoch

I have an array which contains time in `HH:mm:ss` format.

I want to convert this into epoch time. To convert a particular time into epoch, date along with time should be passed.

I want to pass today's date along with the time from array.

For example `09:15:30` (date `22/12/2011`) which is a string, should be converted into 1324525530000 (corresponding epoch value)

How should I convert this ??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can get an idea looking at this snippet:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithSafeDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSTimeInterval epoch = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Anyway you can have a look to NSDateFormatter and NSDate in the reference docs.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an epoch time in milliseconds - as far as I know it's supposed to be in seconds.

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to parse a string and convert it to a `NSDate`. This date can then return the seconds since 1970. If you really need it, simply multiply this by 1000.

Comment: You have to pass the datetime format for it to know what to parse.

Comment: (untested) `NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"theformat"]; NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:@"22/12/2011 09:15:30"]; [df release];` - you may want to view [this page on date formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the format. "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" might work for you.

Comment: I thought it'd be obvious, but: `[convertedDate timeIntervalSince1970]` will give that.

Comment: I'd like to redirect you to the [NSDate docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)